# apex candlestickchart with overflow graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I am creating a candle stick chart with ApexCharts on reactJs. So its a price chart showing OHLC for each candle. Now I want the chart to display a fixed number of data points (lets say 10 data points) and as new data comes in, old data should scroll out of view horizontally. Meaning i can scroll to the left to view the old data. Any idea for this?

Below is my current code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Chart from 'react-apexcharts';

const CandlestickChart = () => {
  const chartRef = useRef(null);
  const maxDataPoints = 10; // Maximum number of data points to display
  const [seriesData, setSeriesData] = useState([
    {
      data: [
        { x: new Date('2024-03-11').getTime(), y: [650, 660, 640, 650] },
        { x: new Date('2024-03-12').getTime(), y: [652, 662, 645, 655] },
        { x: new Date('2024-03-13').getTime(), y: [655, 670, 650, 660] },
        { x: new Date('2024-03-14').getTime(), y: [660, 675, 655, 670] },
        { x: new Date('2024-03-15').getTime(), y: [665, 680, 660, 675] }
      ]
    }
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeriesData(prevData => {
        const currentDate = new Date(prevData[0].data[prevData[0].data.length - 1].x);
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1); // Increment the date by one day

        // Simulating new data point
        const newDataPoint = {
          x: currentDate.getTime(),
          y: [
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 600, // Open
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 700, // High
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 500, // Low
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 600  // Close
          ]
        };

        // Create a new array with updated data

      const updatedData = [{
       data: [...prevData[0].data, newDataPoint]
      }];

        return updatedData;
      });
    }, 1000); // Update every 10 seconds

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ overflowX: 'auto' }}>
      <Chart
        options={{
          chart: {
            type: 'candlestick',
            height: 350
          },
          xaxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
          }
        }}
        series={seriesData}
        type="candlestick"
        height={350}
        ref={chartRef}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CandlestickChart;
```